# How to create DB entries in a model with foreign keys - best practice?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

is there a better way to get this in Laravel working?

I am trying to create a Main Id in Table Tickets and then with this ID create a new entry, linking them with foreign key and having a reference.

Appretiate opinions, but would like to get reference to documentation as well.

Thx for your feedback,
Christian

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Ticket;
use App\TicketHeader;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TicketController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function createTicket(Request $request) 
    {


        $request->validate([
            'TicketTitle' => 'required|max:150',
            'TicketDescription' => 'required',
        ]);

        DB::transaction(function() use ($request) {

            // Erstellt ein Master Satz in Tickets, holt dort die ID um in Headers weitere Daten einzuführen.
            $ticket = new Ticket;
            $ticket -> save();
            // ID des letzten eingeführten
            $ticketID = $ticket->id;


            // Erstellt Daten in TicketHeader
            $ticketHeader = new TicketHeader;
            $ticketHeader->HeaderId = $ticketID;
            $ticketHeader->TicketTitle = $request->TicketTitle;
            $ticketHeader->TicketDescription = $request->TicketDescription;
            $ticketHeader->save();

        });

        return response()->json($request->all(), 201); 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

While you could get by with way you are doing it, there are certainly some things you could do to gain more control over both the process of storing the Models and the response, as well as improving the readability of your code should someone else need to pick it up later.

**Manual transactions**

The first thing I would do is to use manual transactions. This will allow you to control the response if an error occurs, gives you the ability to throw your own errors, and will also allow you to return your newly created Ticket model instead of the Request values — this is a better indication of success and will contain the new Model's `id`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions

**Eloquent relationships**

The next thing I would do is leverage Eloquent's ability to store relationships without needing to specify the parent Model's `id`.  I am assuming your relationship is defined as Ticket *HasOne* TicketHeader and the method is `ticketHeader()`, but you can update it as necessary.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

**Controllers and methods**

Each Model (e.g., Ticket) should have its own Controller (e.g., TicketController).  Since you are storing a new model, your method should probably conform to the standard `store(Request $request)`.  The `create()` method in a Controller is generally used to return a View which displays a form.  Take a look at the Laravel scaffold within a Controller when created using the resource flag.

`php artisan make:controller ModelController --resource`

https://gist.github.com/matticustard/607ac1e0e36b22e14c7658c65b94915a

https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#resource-controllers

**Sample `store()` method**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'TicketTitle' => 'required|max:150',
        'TicketDescription' => 'required',
    ]);

    // begin the transaction
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {

        // store a new ticket
        $ticket = Ticket::create();

        // store the TicketHeader using the relationship to Ticket
        $ticket->ticketHeader()->save(new TicketHeader([
            'TicketTitle' => $request->TicketTitle,
            'TicketDescription' => $request->TicketDescription,
        ]));

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {

        // roll back database changes on error
        DB::rollBack();

        // log the error
        report($exception);

        // return a custom error response
        return response()->json($exception->getMessage(), 500);
    }

    // commit the database changes (end the transaction)
    DB::commit();

    // return the ticket instead of the request — better indication of success
    return response()->json($ticket, 201);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Going through your code and suggestions help me understand a little bit more laravel and the help the framework can provide. I guess, I am still trying to do a lot manually... the way relations are handled are very powerful.